# How to make polygon volume in TIN surface?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, raster-calculator, tin, volume

I want to measure surface volume of an area in different elevation layer.

For measuring the surface volume I have to make a Polygon Volume as well. I have problem with making this polygon over the TIN layer and define the different elevation for it ? Like the link below:

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00q900000037000000

for example I have a TIN surface which min contour is 25 m and max contour is 140 , then I want to measure all the surface above 25 m , 35 m and ... ! I just wonder how to make this polygon on top?

Comment: Do you really want to calculate the volume in a special area of interest (e.g. your TIN covers Europe but you want to calculate only in area of Norway)? Then use [Surface Volume (3D Analyst)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Surface_Volume/00q900000027000000/). Or do you want to calculate the volume for the whole area (e.g. your TIN covers Europe and you want to calculate the volume in Europe)? Then use [Polygon Volume (3D Analyst)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Polygon_Volume/00q90000003q000000/).

Comment: Sorry, I've swapped the tools. Correct is this:
Calculate in special area of interrest: [Polygon Volume (3D Analyst)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Polygon_Volume/00q90000003q000000/).
Calculate for whole TIN: [Surface Volume (3D Analyst)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Surface_Volume/00q900000027000000/).

Comment: Yes, I just want to calculate 1 km* 1 km area in Norway.
I have a clipped DEM, then made a TIN ,and also made a contour layer.Now I want to overlay a Polygon on TIN surface to cut the area in different elevation. 
I know all the tools , but just wonder the way that I made a polygon is correct or not? 

I made a separate polygon shape file in Arc Map. I add it in Arc Scene.

Need someone to tell me is it correct or no ?

Comment: thanks for your answer
i am interested to know how to automate it with ModellBuilder or Pyhton?
what would be the easiest solution? (i am not very confident in programming...) thank you!

Answer (score 1):

All you need is your (clipped) TIN. You do not need a polygon (or contour lines).

You have to execute [Surface Volume (3D Analyst) tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Surface_Volume/00q900000027000000/) several times.

1. Use Surface Volume (3D Analyst) with `reference_plane` = above and `base_z` = 25. You get the volume above 25 meter.
2. Run tool again with `base_z` = 35. You get the volume above 35 meter.
3. Run tool again with `base_z` = 45. You get the volume above 45 meter.
4. ...

(You can automate it with Modell Builder or Python.)

[image]